# How to clear everything in Mathematica?

Tags: clear

I am a new user. According to a documentation,
Clear["context`*"] clears all symbols in a particular context.

I want to clear everything (functions, variables, etc..)
After I use the above command, my function n1[x,y] is still defined.

Thanks

Comment: try [CleanSlate package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/4718/) I do not know if it still works on V 10 or not. `CleanSlate, tries to do everything possible to return the kernel to the state it was in when the CleanSlate.m package was initially loaded` (I myself, when I want to make sure everything is clear, just restart the kernel)

Comment: They may be looking for Remove

Comment: Beware: `Dynamic` content, including `Manipulate` and `DynamicModule`, in open notebooks can work against simply clearing or quitting the kernel.

Comment: Did you literally execute ``Clear["context`*"]`` or did you try ``Clear["Global`*"]``? Or perhaps another context?

Comment: You have to delete all outputs containing Dynamic or Initialization for DynamicModules since those are going to be evaluated after you quit kernel.

Comment: Another caution: if you sign in to Wolfram Cloud, then you may have objects in the context `CloudObject`.

Comment: Sometimes, the most efficient way is just to exit Mathmematica completely and start it again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This will, as it says, remove all symbols and definitions made in the global context:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
```

Answer (score 13):

As Nasser points out, the command `Quit[]` will quit the kernel completely. It will kill the kernel process, stopping the kernel from using any memory or remembering anything at all. Evaluating any command will re-start the kernel from scratch.