# Simultaneous Equations and Optimization

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I have the following simultaneous equations.

$W=G[V](s+80)+(1-G[V])114$

$V=(1-F[W])(90-s)$

where $F$ and $G$ are cumulative distribution functions of $x$ and $y$. The variables of $x$ and $y$ are distributed according to some distribution respectively.

What I want to know is the minimum value of $1-F[W]$ when $s$ is changed in some range ($30<s<100$).

I solved the simultaneous equations with respect to $W$ and $V$ but was stucked when I try to find a minimum of $1-F[W]$. I could plot the graph and I could see where the minimum would be graphically.

How can I use FindMinimum or NMinimize with the solutions of the simultaneous equations? In the code below, NSolve returns a list of rules. I would like to know how I can use this list of rules to derive the minimum of $1-F[W]$.

I greatly appreciate your help.

```
mx = 240
dx = 100
my = 10
dy = 10
x = TruncatedDistribution[{0, ∞}, NormalDistribution[mx, dx]]
y = TruncatedDistribution[{0, ∞}, NormalDistribution[my, dy]]
f[z_] := PDF[x, z]
F[z_] := CDF[x, z]
g[z_] := PDF[y, z]
G[z_] := CDF[y, z]
sol = NSolve[{W == G[V]*(s + 80) + (1 - G[V])*114 && 
    V == (1 - F[W])*(90 - s)}, {V, W}]
Plot[1 - F[W] /. sol, {s, 30, 100}]
```

Comment: Concrete code for the functions would be helpful...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I added my codes.

Comment: Please post something that will parse correctly on copy-paste. And avoid using `Symbolize`, `SubscriptBox` and the like.

Comment: I'm sorry! Corrected the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; Remove["Global`*"];
mx = 240;
dx = 100;
my = 10;
dy = 10;
a = 100;
b = 1/2;
x = TruncatedDistribution[{0, \[Infinity]}, 
NormalDistribution[mx, dx]];
y = TruncatedDistribution[{0, \[Infinity]}, 
NormalDistribution[my, dy]];
f[z_] := PDF[x, z];
F[z_] := CDF[x, z];
g[z_] := PDF[y, z];
G[z_] := CDF[y, z];

eq = Simplify[{W == G[V]*(s + 80) + (1 - G[V])*114, 
V == (1 - F[W])*(90 - s)}, Assumptions -> {V > 0, W > 0}];

func[S_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[eq /. s -> S, {{V, 1/2}, {W, 1/3}}]

Plot[1 - F[Evaluate[(W /. func[s])]], {s, 30, 100}]
```

[image]

```
NMinimize[1 - F[Evaluate[(W /. func[s])]], s, Method -> "NelderMead", 
WorkingPrecision -> 20] // Quiet

(*{0.84757806941877589235, {s -> 66.588713327134220158}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I learned a lot from your codes. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Mariusz, why do you remove the "Global`*" you just cleared from?

Comment: @CATrevillian .See:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89846/how-to-clear-everything-in-mathematica/89851#89851 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-do-i-clear-all-user-defined-symbols

Comment: Mariusz, thank you for the links! Those did a bit to clarify the difference between the two, though it still does not ring properly to me--can you help to clarify why you operate with this, I suppose I would call it, workflow? Does it free up the memory, in opposition to `ClearAll` merely removing the defined values? Do you use it here to account for any variances in previously defined Global variables, as opposed to creating a local context to avoid this? I should have specified I was hoping for you to clarify in your answer, why you take this unique starting point? Very nice finds & code!

Comment: @CATrevillian . https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37624/remove-versus-clearall

Comment: Mariusz, hah! Perfect! Thank you! As an aside, I appreciate your conviction & +1 in the provision of links to requests for (very clearly to me now) easily answered requests for clarification/confusion resolution. As well all know, the SE search can be a bit...difficult, so, very truly thank you for these links and helping to clarify what will now be a pivitol part of my workflow! :D